# Create Palette Image with Multiple Rows Using ImageMagick

Tags: colors, imagemagick

I have learned how to generate a palette image from a source image using ImageMagick:

```
convert source.png -colors 256 -unique-colors -scale 1000% palette.png
```

An image with a single row of colors, such as the following, is output:

[image: Single row palette]

However, I would like set a value to limit the number of squares/columns, & start a new row when that number is reached. So the output should look more like this:

[image: Multi-row palette]

Is it possible to do this with ImageMagick? Or is there another method to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do, for example, is crop the long line into 4 parts (each of 25%), and then join them one under the other (`-append`):

```
convert source.png -colors 256 -unique-colors -scale 1000% \
 -crop 25%x100% -append palette.png
```

This is not quite what you asked for, but by varying the percentage you can vary the crop point, or you can use a fixed width in pixels, like `-crop 63x100%` to get exactly the example output you provided.

Comment: This is what I needed. But I did slightly change the command to suit what I wanted. I avoided using a percentage in *crop* argument:

`$ convert source.png -colors 255 -unique-colors -scale 1000% -crop 120x10 -append -type Palette palette.png`. Using 100% instead of 10 (pixels) seems to change the outcome.